# MongoDB. Searching substring in string field

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search

Currently, I have a MongoDB instance, which contains a collection with a lot of entities. Each entity contains a string attribute, which represents some text. My goal is to provide a strict text search in the collection. It should work as a MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM texts
WHERE text LIKE '%test%';
```

MongoDB text index would be great, but it doesn't provide a strict search. How I could organize a strict search for such data? Could I do some optimization?

I already checked other software (such as ElasticSearch, Lucene, MongoDB, ClickHouse), but I haven't found options to do it. Searching as now took too much time.

Answer (score 0):

In  mongoDB you can do it as follow:

```
 db.texts.find({ text:/test/ })
```